# Difference between assigning instantiation to parent class and derived class

Tags: java

If I declare these 2 classes:

```
public class A {
  // attributes
}
public class B extends A {
  // attributes
}

A obj1 = new B();
B obj2 = new B();
```

What is the difference between these two instantiations?

Comment: polymorphism and programming to interfaces.

Comment: To start off. create a totally new method in `B` which is not present in `A`. Try calling it in both cases. Next create a method with same signature in both `B` and `A`. Next, try the same with instance level feilds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *instantiations* are the same. In both cases you are creating a `new B()`.

The *assignments* are different. Because `B` is a `A`, you can assign any expression of type `B` to a variable of type `A`. This can happen without you needing to do explicit casts due to [*assignment contexts* (JLS 8 § 5.2)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) which:

> allow the value of an expression to be assigned to a variable; the type of the expression must be converted to the type of the variable.

In your example, a [*widening reference conversion* (JLS 8 § 5.1.5)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.5) is performed which allows a reference type `S` to be converted to a reference type `T`, provided `S` is a subtype of `T`. The compiler does this automatically for you as it is a widening conversion: i.e. it will always succeed without a `ClassCastException`.

Java needs to allow for this in order to be able to do [*Polymorphism*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html), which allows you to treat a type `S` as any of it's supertypes `T` (e.g. to treat a `Cat` or a `Dog` as an `Animal`); this in turn allows you to put common behaviour (or common contracts - see below for comments about interfaces) into a supertype.

At runtime the actual type is known, and the actual type's methods are called instead of the supertypes methods. So, for `Animal a = new Cat();`, the runtime knows `a` is a `Cat` and calls the implementation of `sleep` on `Cat`, not on `Animal`.

```
public class Animal { public void sleep() { /* close eyes */ } }
public class Cat extends Animal { public void sleep() { /* curlUpAndSleep */ } }
public class Dog extends Animal { public void sleep() { /* stretchOutAndSleep */ } }
...
public void putToBed(Animal a) { a.sleep(); }
...
Animal a1 = new Cat(); // curls up and sleeps
Animal a2 = new Dog(); // stretches out and sleeps - my dog obviously thinks he's a cat
putToBed(a1); putToBed(a2);
```

This whole concept also applies to interfaces which allow you to apply common contracts to objects that don't share a supertype relation:

```
public interface Sleepable { public void sleep(); }
public class Cat implements Sleepable { public void sleep() { /* curlUpAndSleep */ } }
public class Dog implements Sleepable { public void sleep() { /* stretchOutAndSleep */ } }
...
public void putToBed(Sleepable a) { a.sleep(); }
```

Comment: what is the significance of this?.. i mean how is it useful in a program

Comment: @AnmolBhardwaj. It is useful everywhere you apply OO concepts and patterns. It allows you to write using contracts and general behaviour rather than specific implementation. In a practical example that happens inside the Java codebase every day - every class ultimately is a subclass of `Object` which defines `equals`. You can therefore change the notion of equality by implementing your own equals method. `Collection.contains(Object o)` just asks for an `Object` and uses polymorphism to call your actual `equals` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in the ***instantiation***. In both cases you are allocating space on the Heap for a `B` object.

The difference is in the ***assignment*** and the **type** of the reference variables.

```
A obj = new B();
```

In this case, the reference variable `obj` is of type `A` (parent). So when calling behaviours on `obj` you can only call methods that exist in `A`.

```
B obj = new B();
```

In this case, the reference variable `obj` is of type `B` (child). So when calling behaviours on `obj`, you can call methods that have been inherited by the child `B` from its parent `A`, and also methods that only exist in `B`.

Answer (score 1):

In case

```
A a = new B()
```

Instace of type B is created but refference is in parent type. Using it you are not able to access fields or call methods specific for B type.

Answer (score 0):

Let me add some code in your Question...

```
public class A{
void base(){
 print("base method");
}
}
public class B extends A{
void child(){
 print("child method");
}
}
.......

A obj1 = new B(); 
B obj2 = new B();
```

Now Call both method by object

```
obj1.base();   //base method

obj1.child();   //create compile time error
```

because obj1 is an object of B class but the reference is of A class....
obj1 only can call methods which is in Class A

```
//but obj2 can call both methods as it inherits Class A and also having reference of its own.

obj2.base();   //base method

obj2.child();   // child method
```