# How can link to class type create another object of class type

Tags: java, oop

I am new in java, and please ask me what this code is mean?

```
Image img = new ImageIcon("2.png")
```

how can image class type link create another object?

Comment: please elaborate the question?

Comment: Please read about Object-oriented concepts in [The Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html), a Java book etc.

Comment: What that code does mean?

Comment: That code means "Create an object of type `ImageIcon` using the argument `2.png`, and assign a reference to that object to the variable `img` which is of type `Image`".

Comment: Please see: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32434494/difference-between-assigning-instantiation-to-parent-class-and-derived-class

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable of type `Image` can refer to an instance of `ImageIcon` if `ImageIcon` either extends or implements `Image` (directly or indirectly). (I should note that the only `ImageIcon` class I know, [`javax.swing.ImageIcon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) does not and so that code wouldn't compile. Presumably you're using something else.)

In general, a superclass-typed variable can refer to a subclass object, and an interface-typed variable can refer to any object whose class implements that interface. This is vital for polymorphism in Java.

I suggest going through the [Java Inheritance Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) for more. You may also find [my answer to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348199/what-is-the-difference-between-the-hashmap-and-map-objects-in-java/1348228#1348228) useful.

Comment: but what is different if i will write like this - ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("2.png")

Comment: @SasunHakobyan - I suspected that might be what the rest of that comment was going to be. :-) See [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348199/what-is-the-difference-between-the-hashmap-and-map-objects-in-java), in particular [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348199/what-is-the-difference-between-the-hashmap-and-map-objects-in-java/1348228#1348228).